# How to update Ajax call (not content)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at this code please - how could I kill / update or restart an ajax call (not content that Ajax calls) after the content has already been called?

I mean the `$('#posting_main')` is called `onclick` and animated - how to stop ajax and make it another `$('#posting_main')` on another click?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#img_x_ok").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 var post_text = $.trim($("#main_text_area").val());

 var data_text = 'post_text='+ post_text;
 if (post_text === "") return;

 var xhr = $.ajax({

 type: "POST",
 url: "comm_main_post.php",
 data: data_text,
 cache: false,

 success: function (data){
 //content

 $("#posting_main").fadeIn();
 $("#posting_main").load("pull_comm.php");
 $("#main_text_area").attr("value", "");

 $("#posting_main").animate({ 
     marginTop: "+=130px",
 }, 1000 );

 }

 }); //ajax close

 }); }); //both functions close
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [abort the current request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) with:

```
xhr.abort();
```

After having done that, you can run another `$.ajax(...)` to make a second request.

---

You could implement it like the following. Note that indenting code makes it a lot more readable!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     var xhr; // by placing it outside the click handler, you don't create
              // a new xhr each time. Rather, you can access the previous xhr
              // and overwrite it this way

     $("#img_x_ok").click(function(e){

         e.preventDefault();

         var post_text = $.trim($("#main_text_area").val());

         var data_text = 'post_text='+ post_text;
         if (post_text === "") return;

         if(xhr) xhr.abort(); // abort current xhr if there is one

         xhr = $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: "comm_main_post.php",
             data: data_text,
             cache: false,

             success: function (data){
                 //content

                 $("#posting_main").fadeIn();
                 $("#posting_main").load("pull_comm.php");
                 $("#main_text_area").attr("value", "");

                 $("#posting_main").animate({ 
                     marginTop: "+=130px",
                 }, 1000 );

             }

         });

     });

});
```

Comment: Hi...could you be more specific as to where I should place xhr.abort(); I've done it already but the Ajax doesn't run on the first call in this case...

Comment: I think we need to know when and why you want the AJAX call stopped to fully answer your question. Is it in response to an event such as a click?

Comment: @pimvdb It makes sense - but it doesn't work. The Ajax is called and each time I press the button it updates the old div instead executing the new one..

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, I'd like to refresh Ajax after the click and execute it again on another click. When we stop Ajax on a click event you can't execute it on another click on the same button. So the question is how to refresh it each time you press the same post button..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, however:

1. xhr.abort() will kill the AJAX request. After calling abort(), you could modify and resend the request, if desired.
2. $("#posting_main").stop() will stop the fadeIn animation. (And I think you might need to follow that with $("#posting_main").hide() to be sure it isn't left partially visible.)

Comment: HI..the thing is: on first onload of the page I place a comment into $('#main_text_area') and press an image button to post the text. Ajax calls $('#posting_main') ,animates and shows it with the comment inside. Now when I refer back to the text_area and would like to place another comment Ajax still updates the one in $('#posting_main') that has already been called. I'd like to kill the process and make Ajax restart. When I place xhr.abort(); Ajax doesn't execute at all - even on the first call...